# Problem writing function for stratified sampling in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, sampling

I'm trying to write my function to do stratified sampling from a dataframe

```
strSample<-function(x,grp,n) {
frac<-n/nrow(x)
x %>% group_by(grp) %>% sample_frac(.,frac)
}
```

where
'x' is dataframe,
'grp' is grouping variable,
'n' is number of samples to be taken

When I apply this to the 'iris' dataset using

```
strSample(iris,Species,15)
```

it gives me error "Error: Column `grp` is unknown
"

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use `{{}}` : `x %>% group_by({{grp}}) %>% sample_frac(frac)`